# How to search between words or between lines?

Tags: javascript, node.js

How can i find all lines in a file between words or between lines "startString" and "endString"?

```
const fs = require('fs')
const startString = '-----CompilerOutput:-stderr----------'
const endString = '-----EndCompilerOutput---------------'
const file = fs.readFileSync('./history.log', 'utf8')
let arr = file.split(/\r?\n/);
arr.forEach((line, idx)=> {
    if(line.includes(startString, endString)){
        console.log((idx+1)+':'+ line);
    }
})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can slice the file:

```js
const startIndex = file.indexOf(startString) + startString.length;
const endIndex = file.indexOf(endString);
const between = file.slice(startIndex, endIndex);
console.log(between);
```